# R Shiny or Python Dash for real time data streaming / update and real time plotting

Tags: python, r, shiny, shinydashboard, plotly-dash

I have written a Java program to collect real time data and flush data output to a csv file every 30 seconds (without closing the file). Every 30 seconds that data file will replace the existing data with a new set of data collected real time in Java. (FYI The aggregated data will only be 50 MBs max on a daily basis, so I believe it shouldn't consume too much computational power)

Now my goal here is to create a real time streaming web application with external URL that i can have access to it even when I am outside with my mobile phone.

I want my R / Python programme to read that particular csv every 30 seconds and do some data processing (this bit is just data analysis and aggregation which i know). Then after data processing, the new data points can be added to the plots real time.

Apologies for asking this stupid question, as I know nothing about web application programming. What is the procedure for creating this external URL ? Do I just make it up or do I have to pay for it ?

Is this real time data streaming / plotting possible ?If yes, is this most efficiently and easily done using the R's `Shiny` library or Python's `Dash` package? Are there any pitfalls that I should be aware of ?

I understand that this question seems to be a bit broad. Nonetheless, I would like gain an understanding of wokrflow in terms of which packages to use, where to start and how to start, so I can ask more specific questions later on.

Comment: Yes, it is easy to implement with R shiny package. Just create a shiny UI with table output and refresh it with every 30 seconds.

Comment: A simple example here :
https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/0.12.1/tableOutput.html

Comment: is it possible to gain access to the shiny server from externally, i.e. internet ?

Comment: Yes, you can install a free version of shiny server on linux system and deploy your shiny app on it.

Comment: Or you can use http://shinyapps.io/

Comment: Sorry for being repetitive. I will be running the Java Program, collecting the data throughout the day using my desktop at home and the desktop will also continuously process and publish these data to the shiny app. My goal is to be able to have access of this shiny app from a different computer say my laptop (different wifi network) just to view the latest plot only. In this case, what is the easiest way to view the app from another computer given all the computers have Rstudio installed?

Comment: You can listen your shiny app on a specific port and run with Rstudio, and setting your router to make this port public to the internet, so everyone on the internet with your IP address and this port can access your shiny app.

Comment: It would be great if you write an answer outlining how to listen to my shiny app on a specific port and the steps to make this port public to the internet.

Comment: There is an argument called  `port` in `runApp` function. and you can google it how to use `port forwarding` on you router.

Comment: Can I do options(shiny.port=8888)’instead of ‘runApp’ and then port forward would there be a difference ?

Comment: Those are basically the same, when you change port with `options(shiny.port=8888)`, it will also change the default port in `runApp`, see :https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/1.0.1/runApp.html